# Salesforce Lightning Experience Bell Notifications

Tags: lightning-experience

I have the following problem, I do not know how to enable notifications to appear in the lightning experience bell.

I created the tasks and assignments, I create events, I make mention to my user in conversations and in no case I appear in the bell a notification.

Is there a way to configure notifications? to know why you do not show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Notifications alert](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_sales_notifications_sfx.htm) your users when key events occur in Salesforce that they should know about or that require their attention—such as when they receive approval requests or are mentioned in Chatter posts. Lightning Experience includes a list of notifications that users can quickly access from any page.

It will not work if you mention yourself in chatter. To see this in action

1. Login as user A
2. Chatter post using User A -> User B
3. Login as user User B and see notification

Comment: ok, I understand that with chatter works like this, but if I am user A and I create a task and assign it to user A does not show it to me as a notification, should show it? or will never be notifications of tasks created by the same user?

Comment: it will not show that as this is same user. There is one open idea to support this as general https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CORPQA4

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Salesforce has given a new feature in summer 19 release. You can send bell icon notifications in desktop and mobile app as well. This feature is available in Process builder. Please find url for more information.
[link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_notificationbuilder.htm)

Answer (score 1):

New capability in Summer '19 that will be very useful is being able to Keep Users in the Know with Notification Builder : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_notificationbuilder.htm